# Analytic continuation of $g(\sqrt{1-x^2})$ where $g$ is entire

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Consider a function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2},  x\in \mathbb{R}$.  Moreover, let $g:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function and consider the composition
\begin{align}
h(x)= g(f(x))=g(\sqrt{1-x^2})
\end{align}

Question:  Let $H(z)$ be the complex analytic extension of $h(x)$ and let $U$ denote the domain of $H(z)$.  **What is $U$?**

**Some thoughts**

1. I think, since, $g$ is entire we can ignore it.  What I mean is that $U$ will be the domain to which the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ can be extended.  Therefore, we need to find a domain of continuation for $f(x)$. (As phrased this technically wrong. See the comment below for a correct statement).
2. I think the candidate for the extension is $F(z)=\sqrt{1-z^2}, z\in \mathbb{C}$ since $f(x)=F(x),  x \in [-1,1]$.
3. The function $f(x)$ has a power series expansion around zero with a radius of convergence $1/2$. Therefore, it must have analytic continuation at least to $|z|<1/2$.

**Edit** Based on the comments and suggestions. Let's restrict our attention only to the principle branch of square root.

Comment: I don't completely agree with (1). For instance, if $g$ is a constant function or the function $z \mapsto z^2$, then you can actually get $U = \Bbb C$. What I do agree with is the fact that the $U$ you get for $f$ is the "best possible" in the following sense: No matter what $g$ is, $U$ will be in the domain of $H$. Moreover, there does exist a $g$ for which the domain is exactly $U$. (Namely, $g$ being the identity function works.)

Comment: As for extending $f$, you should look up "branch points" or maybe someone can expand on that. You wouldn't get a unique maximal $U$ however. For example, just consider the continuation of $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$. You can define a branch of square root (or a branch of $\log$) on any set of the following form: Consider $\Bbb C$ and remove a ray emanating from $0$ (you remove $0$ from the domain).

Comment: @AryamanMaithani  Thank you for these comments. This is very helpful.   I have edited my answer. I wanted to restrict my solution to the principle branch of the square root.

Comment: To clarify, at this stage the question is _What is the domain of $F(z) = \sqrt{1 - z^2}$?_ (with the radical sign denoting the principal branch), right?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  Yes, I think so.

Comment: Does that not answer the question...? :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  Yeah. I think it almost is.  I am somewhat confused because I thought analytic extensions are unique.   But here we have several extensions depending on which branch we choose.

Comment: There is only one _principal_ branch....

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang but when I start with $\sqrt{x}$  aren't all possible complex branches of this function different functions?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand, but if we pick the principal branch, we're committing to a domain of extension, namely the set $U$ where $1 - z^2$ is not non-negative real, and $h$ extends to $U$ uniquely as a holomorphic function.